# Meta box on options page save form problem

Tags: plugin-development, metabox

I have follow code from this link, https://gist.github.com/757903 and I have manage to create several metaboxes on my custom options page under Settings section.
Stuff that doesn't work for me are :

1. I can't make it work, so save form work, I think that this hook doesn't exists "add_action('admin_post_save_howto_metaboxes_general', array(&$this, 'on_save_changes'));"
2. When I move boxes around, next time when I come back to that page, order of meta boxes is not saved, same thing for columns layout.

Can someone help me with this please.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to define areas and put metaboxes in them, you must define the layout via the current screen.

For example, when displaying a dashboard esque widget area on my custom option page, the first things I have are:

```
global $screen_layout_columns;
add_screen_option('layout_columns', array('max' => 3, 'default' => 3) );
$screen = get_current_screen();
wp_enqueue_script( 'dashboard' );
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late response, thank you, I have found this, http://chrismarslender.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-screen-options-tutorial/ , but your answer really help me, any idea for my second question?